# Using ajax and jQuery to auto fill in a form but its only working sometimes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Im trying to get the form "add Enrolment" to automatically fill in when the edit button is clicked, it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't, the Get Enrolment always returns the correct result but the javascript file doesn't set the value in the form everytime time.

HTML:

```
<p><input type="button" id="addEnrolment" value="Add" class="button-add"></p> 
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title="Enrolment Form">
    <form id="addEnrolmentForm" name="myform" method="post" action="" >
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" >
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> School </td>
    <td><select name="school"  id="school" onchange='change_category2(this.value);'>
        <option value="--" >Select An Option: </option>
        <option value="Moosomin">Moosomin</option>
        <option value="Wapella">Wapella</option>
    </select></td>              
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Age Group </td>
        <td><div class="selectbox" id="responce_event0">
        <select name="agegrp" id="agegrp" disabled="disabled" >
        <option value="--" >Select An Option:</option>
        </select>
        </div></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Events </td>
        <td><div class="selectbox" id="responce_event">
        <select name="event" id="event" disabled="disabled" >
        <option value="--" >Select An Option:</option>
        </select>
        </div></td> 
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Athlete Name:</td>
        <td><div class="selectbox" id="responce_event2">
        <select name="athlete" id="athlete" disabled="disabled" >
        <option value="--" >Select An Option:</option>
        <option value="anOption"> An Option </option>
        </select>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="center"><button type="submit" id='enter'> Submit </button></div>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="enrolment">
<table align="left">
    <tr>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>School</th>
        <th>AgeGroup</th>
        <th>Event</th>
    </tr>     
    <tr id="enrolment7">
        <td>
            <form  style='display:inline;' id="editEnrolment7" method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="enrolment_id" value="7" >
            <input type="submit" id="button7" name="submit" value="Edit" class="button-edit">
            </form>
            <form  style='display:inline;'id="deleteEnrolment7" method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="enrolment_id" value="7" >
            <input type="submit" id="button7" name="submit" value="Delete" class="button-delete">
            </form>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Edwards</td>
        <td>Moosomin</td>
        <td>Bantam Boys</td>
        <td>1000 Meter</td>
    </tr>
   </table></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    maxWidth:600,
    maxHeight: 500,
    width: 500,
    height: 450,
    close: function(){ 
    $('#addEnrolmentForm').trigger("reset");

    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Ajax/ajax_reset_event.php",
            success: function(html){
                $("#responce_event").html(html);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Ajax/ajax_reset_athlete.php",
        success: function(html){
            $("#responce_event2").html(html);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Ajax/ajax_reset_age_group.php",
        success: function(html){
            $("#responce_event0").html(html);
        }
    });
    }

    });
    $("#addEnrolment").on("click", function() 
    {

    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });



    $("#addEnrolmentForm").submit(function(e)
    { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var postData = jQuery(this).serialize();
    $("#dialog").dialog("close")
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "AddEnrolment.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: postData,
    success: function(data){
     alert(data); 
     //alert("success");
    }



    });   
    }); 


    $('[id^="editEnrolment"]').submit(function(e)
    { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var editData = jQuery(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Get/GetEnrolment.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: editData,
    success: function(data){

    var form = document.forms['addEnrolmentForm'];
    form.id.value=data.id;
    form.school.value=data.school;
    //alert(data.school);
    //alert(form.school.value);
    change_category2(data.school);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Get/GetEnrolment.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: editData,
        success: function(data){
            form.agegrp.value=data.agegrp;
    //      alert(data.agegrp);
    //      alert(form.agegrp.value);
            change_category(data.agegrp);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Get/GetEnrolment.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: editData,
                success: function(data){
                    form.event.value=data.event;
    //              alert(data.event);
    //              alert(form.event.value);
                    form.athlete.value=data.athlete;
    //              alert(data.athlete);    
    //              alert(form.athlete.value);
    }});        
    }});

    }
    });





    $("#dialog").dialog("open");

    });
    })

function change_category(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Ajax/ajax_get_event.php?age_group_name="+id,
        data:   id,
        success: function(html){
            $("#responce_event").html(html);
        }
    });
    var school = document.getElementById("school").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Ajax/ajax_get_athlete.php?age_group_name="+id+"&school_name="+school,
        data:   id,
        success: function(html){
            $("#responce_event2").html(html);
        }
    });
}
function change_category2(id)
{

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Ajax/ajax_get_age_group.php",
        success: function(html){
            $("#responce_event0").html(html);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Ajax/ajax_reset_event.php",
            success: function(html){
                $("#responce_event").html(html);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Ajax/ajax_reset_athlete.php",
        success: function(html){
            $("#responce_event2").html(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Get Enrolment returns this:

> {"id":9,"school":"Moosomin","agegrp":"Bantam Boys","event":"1000 Meter","athlete":"81"}

ajax_get_athlete

```
<select name="athlete">
   <option value='--' >Select An Option:</option>
   <option value="81">Mark Edwards </option>
<select/>
```

ajax_get_age_group

```
<select name='agegrp' onchange='change_category(this.value);'>
    <option value='--' >Select An Option:</option> 
    <option value='Bantam Boys' > Bantam Boys</option>
    <option value='Bantam Girls' > Bantam Girls</option>
</select>
```

ajax_get_events

```
<select name='event' >
    <option value='--' >Select An Option:</option>
    <option value='1000 Meter'>1000 Meter </option>
<select/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake with the code that is supposed to be in the document ready handler.

You used

```
$(function() {
   // Code
});
```

As far as I know that doesn't bind to the document ready.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Code
});
```

instead. This does the bindings after all the HTML is loaded and should get you in business